# Auto populate fields from Case Objects to Servicenow fields using custom detail page button

Tags: custom-button, salesforce-id

I have a requirement wherein I have to create a custom button, upon clicking it few fields in case should be directly populated in **servicenow**. So, there are 2 user fieds (Requested For & Salesrep), link field & description field.

This is the URL I've created,

```
/rack_sp?id=sc_cat_item&sys_id=4bb14bc2c84f4e0087fd91e81c4cff48&&sysparam_user={!Case.User__c}
  &sysparm_quotelink={!Case.Link__c}
  &sysparm_salesrep={!User.Id}
  &sysparm_description={!Case.Description}
```

but the problem here is only Quotelink field is getting populated & where as me being salesrep, my name is getting populated in the requested for field instead of Sales rep field. The Requested by field should be populated by the custom field "user" on the case object.

Can someone help me out on this.

Thanks,

Comment: `..&&sysparam_user=..` typo? ; for user, I think you need `{!$User.id}`

Comment: I tried that as well, but looks like I'm having a problem at placing field names of Servicenow.

Comment: can you post a link to the servicenow api doc for this endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Check the field API name on the object to make sure you have it correct. `{!User.Id}` will give the Id of the current running user, which might be why your name is showing.

Comment: Hi Zach, Thanks for the reply. Actually the salesrep value is coming in the URL but not in the servicenow field. Can you help on this.